# Firing an event when a specific IP is detected in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, ip

I'm working on a restaurant system that has to pop up a menu tab whenever someone connects to the restaurant's network. I tried doing it by detecting the user ip and seeing if it matches to the restaurant's network it would render a view. But it simply does not work. (Everything has to be in Yii2, which im new to and got no experience)

I reviewed all my folders and file names but it's all correct, the event simply does not run.

Just for context, i got a component that does the detection job, everything is running in that file. The problem seems to be in the actual controller.

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;



class NetworkController extends Controller{

    public function actionNetworkTeste(){
        
        Yii::$app->networkEventManager->on('specificNetworkConnectionDetected', [$this, 'onSpecificNetworkConnectionDetected']);

        return $this->render('networkTeste');
   
    }

    public function onSpecificNetworkConnectionDetected($event){

        //Yii::debug('Funcionou');

        return $this->render('network-alt'); 

        
    }
}


?>
```

I still don't even know if it is the right path to make a tab pop up when someone connects to the network, but it's way better than to not even try. I'd appreciate some help as i got no experience  in yii2

Comment: I don't see how you expect this to work. PHP runs on a server. It has no way to know what a user's device is doing until that device chooses to talk to it. What you probably need is a captive portal, but configuring that will depend on the capabilities of your customer's router, and may not involve your Yii2 system at all.

Comment: Events doesn't work this way. In a simple way, you need a condition something like `if ($request->ip() === '127.0.0.1') { return $this->render('network-alt'); } return $this->render(''networkTeste');`

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you trying to show extra popup when the website is visited from device connected to restaurant's network or are you trying to force displaying popup once the device is connected to restaurant network? The first thing is quite easy and can be done with simple condition similar to one suggested by SiZE. The second thing is impossible to do with only PHP app.

Answer (score 0):

You should read Yii2 documentation on [handling request](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-overview)

To get client's IP, the documentation is [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-requests#client-information), request API documentation [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request)

```
$userHost = Yii::$app->request->userHost;
$userIP = Yii::$app->request->userIP;
```